# UWP/WinRT: Are multiple asynchronous tasks guaranteed to complete in the order created?

Tags: asynchronous, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, c++-cx

I have a Textbox that I want to constantly save to disk every time it is updated. I've data-bound a property to its contents, and I'm planning on adding code in the property's setter to save on change. I'm familiar with the Textbox UpdateSourceTrigger property.

Each call to save will make a call to `WriteTextAsync`. If the Textbox is saving every time somebody types into it, this could be generating a ton of asynchronous save calls. My simple question is, are the asynchronous write calls guaranteed to not collide and to execute in the order in which their asynchronous tasks were created?

I've read through the [guides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt187335.aspx) on asynchronous programming for Universal Windows Platform, and I can't find anything expressly stating this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't find anything expressly stating this.  This is just the nature of multithreaded development.

```
this could be generating a ton of asynchronous save calls
```

Your common sense is correct.  Problems that could arise:
Saves could finish out of order.
If you close and open the file each time, Saves could collide with each other causing access exceptions.

```
My simple question is, are the asynchronous write calls guaranteed to not collide and to execute in the order in which their asynchronous tasks were created?
```

Nope.  They are guaranteed to collide at some point and at some point are guaranteed to finish execution out of order from what you start them in.  Limitted testing would likely show that it is ok but you'll risk the problems stated above and it would be bad practice.

You could create a manager that keeps track of the changes.  The manager would put all requested changes in a queue and the Manager is the only thread that updates the text file.